# Spring Integration jmsmessage-driven-channel-adapter with IBM MQ

Tags: spring-integration, jms-topic

I have written code to read message from IBM MQ using Spring Integration JMS-message-driven-channel-adapter but not able to read message from queue can anybody help me out below is my configuration.

```
<beans:bean id="ibmJmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <beans:property name="transportType" value="1"/>
    <beans:property name="queueManager" value="***"/>
    <beans:property name="hostName" value="**"/>
    <beans:property name="port" value="**" />
    <beans:property name="channel" value="***"/>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="receiverQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="****"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="****"/>
</beans:bean>
<integration:channel id="componentInfoChannel" />

 <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="componentInfoAdapter" connection-factory="ibmJmsConnectionFactory" destination="receiverQueue" channel="componentInfoChannel" 
         />

<integration:service-activator id="componentInfoActivator"
        input-channel="componentInfoChannel" ref="componentInfoConsumer"
        method="componentInfoListen" />
```

Above configuration is working but failing when I added logging adapter its continously printing warning on console .Detail are mention below .

```
<integration:logging-channel-adapter
        id="componentInfologger" level="INFO" />
    <integration:wire-tap id="componentInfoWireTap"
        channel="componentInfologger" pattern="*" order="2" />
    <integration:logging-channel-adapter
        id="logger" log-full-message="true" level="INFO" />

   2017-02-23 00:09:05.093  WARN [componentdatafiles,48f69e84ab395754,ebf4ae7f3b812a01,false] 90072 --- [ter.container-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  :  Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.LogbackMDCAdapter.put(LogbackMDCAdapter.java:110)
    at org.slf4j.MDC.put(MDC.java:147)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.log.Slf4jSpanLogger.logStartedSpan(Slf4jSpanLogger.java:48)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.trace.DefaultTracer.createChild(DefaultTracer.java:170)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.trace.DefaultTracer.createSpan(DefaultTracer.java:72)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.messaging.TraceChannelInterceptor.startSpan(TraceChannelInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.messaging.TraceChannelInterceptor.preSend(TraceChannelInterceptor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:538)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:415)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap.preSend(WireTap.java:168)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:538)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:415)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap.preSend(WireTap.java:168)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:538)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:415)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap.preSend(WireTap.java:168)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:538)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:415)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap.preSend(WireTap.java:168)
```

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate more? What are symptoms? How does the problem look? There is nothing in your config. Some logs, StackTraces, test-cases etc, please.

Comment: Edited my question please look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for delay. So, I guess your `id="logger"` is redundant component. And the problem is exactly with the `<integration:wire-tap>` and combination with the `TraceChannelInterceptor`.

I mean that you use here Spring Cloud Sleuth.

Would you mind sharing `DEBUG` for the `org.springframework.integration` category meanwhile I'm trying to reproduce an issue locally.

Plus you can exclude `componentInfologger` from the tracing to avoid that `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

I think it happens somehow that we loop tracing via `wire-tap`.

Comment: No-op. Need simple Spring Boot application from you to play. I guess it can be already without JMS. Looks like you have a recursion somehow in your config...

Comment: Thanks Artem got the issue, its due to duplicate id logger and Logger object is created from LoggerFactory in two diffrent class with same class name ComponentInfoConsumer.class . closing question